# How to use querySelector() to find unique class div id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to get the id="myDropdownTop" to toggle the respected drop down menu. This issue is my script part of the code seems to be incorrect, specifically the last line: 
`("div.dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");`
seems to not work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <section id="bracket">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="split split-one">
            <div class="round round-one current">
              <div class="round-details">Round 1<br /><span class="date">August 9</span></div>
              <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">
                  <button class="btn drop-down-btn"><span class="seed">01</span><span id="team1">&nbsp;</span><span class="score">&nbsp;</span></button>
                  <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">
                  <button class="btn drop-down-btn"><span class="seed">32</span><span id="team1">&nbsp;</span><span class="score">&nbsp;</span></button>
                  <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                    <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
    .
    .
    .

    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll("li.team").forEach(function(teamDom) {
          teamDom.querySelector("button.drop-down-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
            teamDom.querySelector("div.dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
          });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Expected result looks like:

[image]

I can achieve this result using  type method. But I have 32 button class that the user can click on, so it needs to adapt to that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to get the results you need. Instead of setting up event handlers for each set of items, just use event delegation where you set up a single event handler at an ancestor of the elements you care about and then let the event (triggered at some descendant) bubble up to the ancestor where it is handled. Then, in the handler you can check to see what element actually triggered the event and act accordingly.

```js
// Get reference to ancestor of elements that need the same handler
let parent = document.querySelector(".matchup");

// Set up event handler on ancestor
parent.addEventListener("click", function(event){

// Check if actual event instigator was what we want
  if(event.target.classList.contains("drop-down-btn")){
    // Toggle the next sibling of the clicked element
    event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
.seed, .team1, .score { pointer-events:none; }
```

```html
<ul class="matchup">
  <li class="team team-top">
     <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
       <span class="seed">01</span>
       <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
       <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
     </button>
     <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content hidden">
       <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button><br>
       <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button><br>
       <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button><br>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="team team-bottom">
     <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
       <span class="seed">32</span>
       <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
       <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
     </button>
     <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content hidden">
       <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button><br>
       <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button><br>
       <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button><br>
     </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```